# Download Excel Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have an entry in my API that returns an excel, I have managed to get it to my Angular 4 service. But I did not extract it from the body and download it from a button in my web application:

```
prls(req?: any): Observable<ResponseWrapper> {
    const options = createRequestOption(req);
    options.params.set('findAll', req.findAll);
    options.params.set('prlPendiente', req.prlPendiente);
    options.params.set('inicioCaduca', req.inicioCaduca);
    options.params.set('finCaduca', req.finCaduca);
    return this.http.get(this.resourceUrl+'/open/excel', options)
        .map((res: Response) =>
        res); 
}
```

In the body of "res" is the file

Answer (score 0):

you need to set response type

```
const option = new RequestOptions();
option.responseType = ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer;
```

so your function should be like

```
prls(req?: any): Observable<ResponseWrapper> {
    const options = createRequestOption(req);
    options.params.set('findAll', req.findAll);
    options.params.set('prlPendiente', req.prlPendiente);
    options.params.set('inicioCaduca', req.inicioCaduca);
    options.params.set('finCaduca', req.finCaduca);
   option.responseType = ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer;
    return this.http.get(this.resourceUrl+'/open/excel', options)
        .map((res: Response) =>
        res); 
}
```

do not forget to import

```
import 'rxjs/Rx' ;
import {HttpInterceptor} from './http-interceptor.service';
```